# <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation

Am trying to do this animation on a view, To Scale it to (0,0) then Move this frame using CGRectMake method and scale it back to (1,1).
So I used the following Code to do this

```
-(void)startWalkAnimationStartWalkingBtnViewScaleToZero{
    CGAffineTransform transform = StartWalkBtnView.transform;

    StartWalkBtnView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(transform,1.0f, 1.0f);
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.7
                          delay: 0.6
                        options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{ StartWalkBtnView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                          animations:^{
                                              StartWalkBtnView.frame=CGRectMake(92, 270, 120, 121);
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                              StartWalkBtnView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(transform,0.0f, 0.0f);
                                              [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.7
                                                                    delay: 0.8
                                                                  options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                                                               animations:^{ StartWalkBtnView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                                                               }
                                                               completion:^(BOOL finished){}
                                               ];
                                          }];
                     }
     ];
}
```

But After trying to run this Animation I got the following error in the Console.

```
Jun 17 12:02:49 Kareem.local MyAppName[3157] <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.
```

I googled for this too much, and have tried all the solutions provided (Scale Near to zere Value,...) but nothing worked, Do any one has an idea for solving this.
Thanks for help

***UPDATE:***
I found that the problem in the following line:

StartWalkBtnView.frame=CGRectMake(92, 270, 120, 121);

But Actually I don't know how to solve the problem, But when I removed this line It scaled to zero then back from zero normally without any errors

Comment: Try (transform,0.01f, 0.01f); instead of (transform,0.0f, 0.0f);

Comment: check out http://sokol8.blogspot.in/2011/05/cgaffinetransforminvert-singular-matrix.html

Comment: @Raj, Thanks for commenting, But I have wrote that I tried this solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **content of the web page** may be the cause of this error, not your iOS app programming.

I found the error occurred in my app only while on [Yahoo](http://www.Yahoo.com/). *Google.com*, no problem. *Reuters.com*, no problem. *SeattleTimes.com*, no problem. Back to *Yahoo.com*, **problem**. Especially while scrolling when the error may appear a few times in a split second.

More detail on [my blog](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2013/08/poor-yahoo.html).

Comment: Baidu.com also has this problem.╮(╯▽╰)╭

Comment: How could web page content cause an iOS app to attempt a transformation with a singular matrix? Geometrically this means transforming some shape to a shape with at least one fewer dimensions. That loses information that cannot be recovered thus it cannot be inverted.

Comment: @Tim The bug lives in some Apple library, presumably WebKit, not our apps. The behavior (error when displaying certain web pages) is consistent, repeatable, and confirmed independently by other developers. As in my case, my app has no calls to CoreGraphics and no matrices.

Answer (score 17):

You get this error because the determinant of your scaling matrix is zero. When you attempt to change the transform to scale 1.0, Core Graphics tries to find the inverse matrix of your previous transformation to return the transformation to identity matrix. With determinant 0 this results in a non-inversible matrix, and that's why you get this error. Don't transform scale to 0.0.

Are you sure you checked with near zero values in **both** scalings you set to 0.0 now?

**Edit (Answer):**

- So, from [Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2042642/raj)'s comment, for avoiding this error, you have to try a value not equal to zero (but very near to zero).

That is, instead of:

```
(transform,0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Try:

```
(transform,0.01f, 0.01f);
```

or

```
(transform,0.001f, 0.001f);
```

Comment: Surely this answer should have the Answered tick? As it says a singular matrix is one with a zero determinant. (transform, 0,0) collapses the shape to (0,0) from whence it cannot return. That's what xCode is complaining about. (0.1,0.1) just shrinks it a lot.